# Can't execute this c# program! Cant find errors myself

Tags: c#

I just started learning c# and what classes and objects are. In the code below I want to able to just type `c.circle();` and print every information about this circle like radius, area etc., but when I run it, it doesn't give me any output on the console screen.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.circle();
    }
}

class Circle
{
    private double radius = 1.0;

    public void circle()
    {
        getradius();
        getarea();
    }

    public double getradius()
    {   
        return radius;
    }

    public double getarea()
    {
        double area = 3.141 * radius * radius;
        return area;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Console.WriteLine` to write to the console. You aren't calling it, so nothing is written. For example, use `Console.WriteLine(getradius());` rather than `getradius();`.

Comment: You don't print anything to the console screen. So nothing appears. Did you expect it to print something? Which line exactly did you think would print something to the console?

Comment: `Circle c = new Circle(); Console.WriteLine("Radius: {0}, Area: {1}", c.getradius(), c.getarea());` and finally you need to keep the console open or it will be too fast and you will not see nothing so write this: `Console.Read();` and now as soon as you type a single character the console will then close.

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, your implementation of `.circle` doesn't return a value or display either of the ones it receives from its own calls.

Comment: You likely want to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi(v=vs.110).aspx instead of `3.14`.

Answer (score 1):

The method "circle()" doesn't print anything to the console.
If you want it to print something you could add the following code in the circle method:

```
Console.WriteLine(getradius());
Console.WriteLine(getarea());
```